# How can i make my next view controller change depending on what the title on the button on the first VC is?

Tags: swift, button, uiviewcontroller, segue

Basically my aim is for if the title of the button on the VC is something, the button will take the user to a a certain other VC, different to if the button title was something else .... 
I dont have a segue as i cant make it go to two places ?

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var buttonName: UIButton!

    var text:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.buttonName.setTitle(self.text, for: .normal)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                  if text == "sad" {
                   _ = segue.destination as! act1ViewController
                  }
                  else if text == "yay" {
                   _ = segue.destination as! act2ViewController
                  }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a `func` inside a `func`. That is pointless (here). Your inner `func` is not going to make anything happen; it is effectively ignored.

Do not *declare* any `func` inside `buttonPressed`. You need to *call* a function that does what you want.

If the goal is to make a segue happen, *call* the function `self.performSegue...`. If there are no segues in your storyboard, *call* the function `self.present...` or `self.pushViewController...`.